# How to manage logins in two yii2 applications which use same database

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

1. I have two backend applications which use same database. If a user logs into one application and navigate other application url in another tab it loads inner pages without login to that application. Is this possible to restrict that or is this expected functionality?

   ```
   Application 1 - www.test.com/app1
   Application 2 = www.test.com/app2
   ```
2. I have to set who can access one application and who can access second application. Is it possible to do so? Is it possible to do with RBAC? Currently we implement permission based table set and try to check permission when login and navigating pages whether pages have sufficient privileges to do so.

Thanks

Comment: You can adapt RBAC to work like you expect.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Can manage both applications using RBAC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the name for the session cookie that is generated, my guess is that you are experiencing this because the name for the session cookie in both the apps is the same, and you are using the same browser to verify the App2 when you login to APP1, which forces the browser to read the same cookie for the session and finds you are already logged in.

Change them in the configs for both the applications like below

Application 1

```
'session' => [
    // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the backend
    'name' => 'app1-frontend',
    'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
    'cookieParams' => [
        'httpOnly' => true,
    ],
],
```

Application 1

```
'session' => [
    // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the backend
    'name' => 'app2-frontend',
    'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
    'cookieParams' => [
        'httpOnly' => true,
    ],
],
```

if you want separate logins for the frontend and backend you can do the same for the frontend and backend configs too.

Comment: I got error session table not found. So I changed class as yii\web\Session. Now it is working. I'm using backend application of both yii2 installations. Do I need to update frontend configs? updated config path is - backend/config/main.php

Comment: And also after log into both two applications in two tabs, when tried to logout from one application, it gives 'Unable to verify your data submission' error. So, I navigated into another page and logout successfully. What would be the issue?

Comment: Logout issue solved by adding different csrf params for both applications. path backend/config/main.php. 'request' => [
'csrfParam' => '_backendCSRF',
],
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6123

Comment: you can use  yii\web\Session if you are not using db oriented sessions , the thing is you just need to make all those (frontend,backend) use different cookie file names for sessions if you want them to be recognized as different sessions , either its a single site or 2 different sites using the same db and the same browser @cha